# My cat has started slapping my head/forehead with her claws when she wants to be fed

Tags: cats, behavior, feeding, aggression, surgery

Unfortunately our cat needed to have all her teeth pulled and a couple of other visits to the veterinarian. Fortunately, (we're quite sure) she's not in pain anymore.

However we noticed, that her behaviour has changed a bit towards us, in particular me and not my girlfriend. She's more aggressive now. Before the surgery, she wasn't aggressive at all (probably because of all the pain she was in).

Anyways, one of the behavioural changes is that whenever she's wants to be fed or when it's almost feeding time (3x/day), she slaps me (not my girlfriend) on the head/forehead (including claws). Before the surgery she used to just tap me on my nose without claws.

Does any of your cats slap you on the head when they want to be fed? (She's getting enough food btw.)

(She used to be this gentle cat, but towards me, she's not any more: https://www.reddit.com/r/cats/comments/eb3wdr/this_is_gentle_threeyearsold_zariza_she_had_to/ Lol?)

Comment: I've heard of plenty of cats biting people when they want something, so it seems like a similar sort of thing. https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19988/cat-bites-my-face-at-night-and-when-he-seems-happy?r=SearchResults

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. Your question currently lacks a ... question. This is not a general discussion forum but a Q&A site. Therefore we need you to describe a specific problem and ask a practical question. You do describe a problem, but what is your goal / desired outcome? Please [edit] your post and clarify your question.